# strstr() alternative for bash

Tags: python, bash, awk

I need to search a string for a substring, if the substring is found print the string upto the end of the substring.i.e

```
str="this is a long string"
substring="long"
expected="this is a long"
```

I have tried bash string manipulation and failed. Tried to use an **awk** command, but I can't get it right.
This works if substring is not in a variable, but I require it in a variable since the input varies.

`awk -F'long' '{print $1}' <<<$str`

```
awk -v myvar="$substring"  -F'myvar' '{print $1}' <<<$str
```

prints the whole string.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `expected=${str%"${str#*"$substring"}"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looked for bash only solution, one of the options would be:

```
sfx="${str#*${substring}}"
expected="${str%"${sfx}"}"
```

Which uses prefix removal (of anything + `$substring`) to determine the trailing part. And then uses suffix removal to trim that from `$str` yielding your expected value.

Since you seem to be OK with answers beyond just shell (like using `awk`), here's similar with `sed`:

```
echo "$str" | sed -e 's#^\(.*'"${substring}"'\).*#\1#'
```

-> match the whole line with anything up to and including `$substring` being saved in the first group and replace that line with content of the first matched group.

note: both of these examples are not greedy and will match up to the first `$substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Including error handling for the case that the substring is not present:

```
str="this is a long string"
substring="long"
if [[ $str =~ (.*"$substring") ]]
then
  expected=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo ERROR: Substring not found >&2
fi
```

While the quotes around `$substring` are not necessary for your concrete example, you would need them if `substring` contained special regex characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
# echo "$str" | awk -F'long' '{print $1FS}'

this is a long
```